# KeyError: u"Migration rango.0002_auto_20150905_0345 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new with django and started messing up some things to see what would happened. The thing is I'm kinda screw up right now and would appreciate help.

I deleted some migrations manually and then run

```
manage.py squashmigrations app migration_name
```

And changed some migrations and then running the command again.
The thing is now I'm facing this little bug. The last migration references another one as parent but it doesn't exist right now.

```
(kali)maker@localhost:~/Poker/tango_with_django_project$ sudo python manage.py migrate       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 237, in build_graph
self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 46, in add_dependency
"Migration %s dependencies reference nonexistent parent node %r" % (migration, parent)
KeyError: u"Migration rango.0002_auto_20150905_0345 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'rango', u'0001_squashed_0004_auto_20150904_2325')"
```

Comment: Have you deleted migrations files?

Comment: @Gocht I did, how do I fix it now?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355202/accidentally-deleted-my-django-south-migration-directory

Comment: @Gocht I'm using Django 1.7, can't seem to find schemamigrations, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: use --fake and makemigrations again

Answer (score 1):

in my case,

1. Drop the db (pls backup/export the data)
2. Delete *.pyc files in migrate folder
3. Delete migration files in migrate folder, except for **init**.py
4. Create new database with the same name
5. Give privilige for user db
6. Makemigrations
7. Migrate
8. Createsuperuser
9. Runserver

And finally, it works.